# Voting to close loads a question's entire content on the mobile site before you can vote for it

Tags: bug, vote-to-close

I went to vote to close a question on my phone earlier, and got this experience:

1. [Went to close > duplicate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxysT.jpg). The close button is disabled. I need to pick the question this one's a duplicate of, first, and I intend to pick the one right there that everyone else has been voting for.

   I don't know its question number - there's an input box right there, which you can only tell is there from the screenshot because it causes a notch in the right-hand border. That means there's a CSS bug, too, probably.

   I guess I need to tap it to select it before I vote for it. I do so.
2. [The *entire question* loads in the close pane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9itMc.jpg) - the question itself and every answer in full. It takes [a lot of scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6tex.jpg) before I can reach the bottom - see the little green bar on the right hand side? That's my scrollbar. It's not usually that tiny.
3. I reach the bottom after a little while. [There's the close button!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6kAP.jpg)

I didn't need to see all of that to vote for it as a duplicate, especially not in a mobile browser. I don't remember it being like this the last time I voted to close a question on my phone (admittedly, that was months ago).

Apparently on desktop, it loads the question into a scrollable frame!

Comment: Here's the same thing on Meta.SO: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171199/close-as-a-duplicate-on-mobile-lots-of-vertical-scrolling

Comment: March 10! Glad to know the bug hasn't been around for *too* long.